# setInterval just won't work

Tags: javascript, html

setInterval won't work, this is my code:

```
    <script>

    var d = new Date();
    var utc_offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + utc_offset);
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();

function clockUpdater() {
    if(h >= 0 || h <= 5){
        hl = h - 18;
    }else if(h >= 6 || h <= 11 ){
     hl = h - 12;
    }else if(h >= 12 || h <= 17){
     hl = h - 6;
    }else if(h >= 18){
     hl = h - 0;
    }

    /*
    hl = hl - 1;


    if(m>1){
         ml = 60 - m -1;
    }
    */

    ml = 60 - m;
    sl = 60 - s;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hl+":"+ml+":"+sl;

}

    setInterval(clockUpdater, 1000);

</script>

<body>
<div id="timer"></div>
</body>
```

I'm building a timer which has to count down every 6 hours, but the setInterval just won't work and this is actually not working as intended, can someone see where I went wrong?

Comment: What exactly does _"just won't work and this is actually not working as intended"_ mean? What's not happening that should be happening? What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: What is the intended behavior?

Comment: It is intended to count down every 6 hours since 0h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the building of the `h`, `m` and `s` values is done once instead of being done inside the `clockUpdater` function.

That's why the clock can't be updated: you're always writing the same hour.

Move that part (including `d = new Date();`) inside the function.

Comment: Oh yeah, problem solved, thanks! Now I just need to apply the correct logic for the counter to count every 6 hours.